# Return a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have the code below which generates a 1D vector containing equally spaced points from [xmin, xmax]. When I call the function it does not return the vector VX. What am I doing wrong?

```
double meshGen1d( double xmin, double xmax, int k )
{
    int i;
    int nV = k + 1;
    boost::multi_array< double, 1 > VX( boost::extents[ nV - 1 ] );

    //std::vector< double > VX( nV - 1 );

    std::cout<<" Setting up the 1D mesh "<<std::endl;

    //Generate node coordinates
    VX[0] = xmin;

    for ( i=0; i<nV; i++ )
    {
        VX[ i ] = VX[ i - 1 ] + ( xmax - xmin ) / k;
    }
    return VX;
}
```

Comment: If you want to return a vector then you need to change the return type of the function.  Right now you have it as a double.

Comment: that worked I have just copied boost::multi_array<double, 1> instead of double .

Answer (score 0):

The original `VX` object is destroyed when the scope of your function `meshGen1d` ends.
You could pass in the object by reference, like this:

```
void meshGen1d(double xmin, double xmax, int k, boost::multi_array<double, 1>& VX )
{
    // ...
}
```

This will prevent creating (and destroying) an extra copy, which might be useful if the object is large in memory.

Comment: Instead of an amendment, you should just delete the second paragraph (and the first one, because it is consequently irrelevant). That is a terrible idea and should *never* be done. Also, regarding "avoid copies", [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: You mean the pass-by-reference part? if so: could you please explain why it is terrible

Comment: No, I mean the *"you should create it with new, and destroy it outside this function with delete."* part. The second paragraph. The pass-by-reference is acceptable, though not my personal preference when the result does not rely on the current state of the argument.

Comment: I agree, that is why i added the pass-by-reference part. The new/delete part is removed.

Comment: Do not fear returning objects. The compiler is often smarter than you, and returning an object here is a great idea because the compiler should be able to elide the copy. Couple that with capturing it by const reference by the caller, or better yet, move semantics, and you have great performance with none of the ugliness.